# Host domain.com in a different server than domain.com/blog

Tags: domain-name-system, php, heroku

How can I point the DNS in order to have /blog and / in 2 different servers?

One of them is on PHPFog (PHP hosting) and the other on Heroku (Rails Hosting).

Regards.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you can't; that's not an issue for the DNS, because it only handles hostnames, not HTTP pathnames on a given host.  Your choices include

1. Host the main site on example.com and blog on blog.example.com, in which case you can do it with the DNS - just publish the relevant A record for each zonefile entry.
2. Host the blog on a disposable domain name, and use ReWrite rules to proxy example.com/blog to the dispoable blog path, rewriting any links on the way through.

1) would be much easier, if you're not wedded to example.com/blog.

Comment: Darn you MadHatter! - This is the better answer @donald.

Comment: I'm just worried with SEO. If I use blog.domain.com I'll lose some SEO juice so I heard.

Comment: Mister Guru: <LARGE GRIN> sorry!  I'll try to be worse!  Donald: SEO juice?

Answer (score 1):

Use a **subdomain** instead: blog.domain.com - many sites do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DNS is what you need to look into to make this happen. I think you'll need to have a redirect setup, if memory serves me right.

You configure this on your webserver.